# How to use fillna on a grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use fillna on a multi-indexed dataframe, and to fill a certain column only while it stays in the same index. The next index might start with the an n/a so I can't call fillna on the column. The size of groups is changing so I can't limit the function by number.

If the df is:

```
1                     Val
fooTitle barTitle        
foo      foo1       valueA
         foo2       NaN
         foo3       NaN
bar      bar1       NaN
         bar2       NaN
         bar3       NaN
         bar4       NaN
baz      baz1       valueB
         baz2       NaN
         baz3       NaN
```

I would like it to be:

```
1                     Val
fooTitle barTitle        
foo      foo1       valueA
         foo2       valueA
         foo3       valueA
bar      bar1       NaN
         bar2       NaN
         bar3       NaN
         bar4       NaN
baz      baz1       valueB
         baz2       valueB
         baz3       valueB
```

I tired using groupby(), but in the guide they specifically say that the group objects are immutable. (They specifically mention fillna:

> Not perform in-place operations on the group chunk. Group chunks
>   should be treated as immutable, and changes to a group chunk may
>   produce unexpected results. For example, when using fillna, inplace
>   must be False (grouped.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(inplace=False)))

)
How can I use the function on each group?

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want to fill with is always the first value as suggested in the question, the following works.

```
df = df.groupby(level= "fooTitle").ffill()
```